# Correct conversion function from C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, arrays

there is a function in C# *(the main task of the function with an [example](https://deck.net/041960e826a057bcdde66c5d2e2c1782))*:

```cs
Int32[] Spiral_Min(Int32[, ] arr) {
    List <Int32> list = new List <Int32> ();
    Int32 n = arr.GetLength(0);
    Int32 count = n;
    Int32 value = -n;
    Int32 sum = -1;
    do {
        value = -1 * value / n;
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            sum += value;
            list.Add(arr[sum / n, sum % n]);
        }
        value *= n;
        count--;
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            sum += value;
            list.Add(arr[sum / n, sum % n]);
        }
    } while (count > 0);
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

I'm trying to do the same in PHP, but i ran into a problem in the code, there is a string:

```
arr[sum / n, sum % n]
```

I do not understand how to do this in PHP, tried it through `array_merge`, but the function still doesn't work.

```php
function f($a)
{
    $n = count($a[0]);
    $count = $n;
    $value = -$n;
    $sum = -1;

    do
    {
        $value = -1 * $value / $n;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $sum += $value;
            $r[] = array_merge($a[$sum / $n], $a[$sum % $n]);
        }

        $value *= $n;
        $count--;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $sum += $value;
            $r[] = array_merge($a[$sum / $n], $a[$sum % $n]);
        }
    }
    while ($count > 0);

    return $r;
}
```

Please tell me what the problem is and how to do it right?

Comment: What does `arr` look like?

Comment: @SalmanA, kind of like a two-dimensional array, `[[1,2,3],[8,9,4],[7,6,5]]` for example

Comment: ah... just use `$arr[$sum / $n][$sum % $n]`. For the above example, `$arr[2][2]` will give you `5`.

Comment: @SalmanA, three cheers, you are my Savior, thank you very much)))*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$arr` is a two dimensional array, you can access elements from the arrays using `$arr[$index1][$index2]` notation. Thus:

```
arr[sum / n, sum % n]
```

Would become:

```
$arr[$sum / $n][$sum % $n]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_push. Like below:

```
function f($a)
{
    $n = count($a);
    $count = $n;
    $value = -$n;
    $sum = -1;
    $r = [];
    do
    {
        $value = -1 * $value / $n;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $sum += $value;
            array_push($r, $a[$sum / $n], $a[$sum % $n]);
        }
        $value *= $n;
        $count--;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $sum += $value;
            array_push($r, $a[$sum / $n], $a[$sum % $n]);
        }
    }
    while ($count > 0);
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: i run there examples of two-dimensional arrays, indicated in the comments what the results should be, but still not what I what I miss? [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/36c0cdc5fb35eb602158120ad59d94a2691e9650)

Comment: I edited the answer ( change the `$n = count($a[0]);` to `$n = count($a);`). Check if that helps